# How to grant VPN access to my own OpenVPN without configuration files

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn

I have created my own VPN service on one my VPS servers and logged in using the configuration files, i was wondering is there an easy/straight forward way to connect to my openvpn service for my community with a naive technical background.

Thanks,